# AWS Lambda Multiple invocations with a random delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm in the process of migrating an existing NodeJS application to run as a Lambda function. So far I've identified that the main function which sends an HTTP POST request can be placed into a Lambda function, however, this function is invoked via a For Loop in which after each iteration has a random delay. The For Loop's iteration count is defined by a user request.

The only way I can think of is having a normal NodeJS process that runs the "Loop" which invokes the lambda. But this defeats the purpose of the serverless/auto-scaling architecture I am trying to create.

Am I able to replace the below for loop & random delay with a serverless/auto-scaling solution?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < userTasks; i++) {
    httpRequestLambda();
    await delay(); // delay can be anywhere from 5 Seconds to 20 Minutes 
  }
```

Comment: AWS Step Functions has a [Wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) that could be used to delay execution of an AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

These are following options you can schedule AWS Lambda;

1. [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)
2. [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html)

Overview of option 1) and option 2) is also available on [this AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/build-scheduler-as-a-service-amazon-cloudwatch-events-amazon-eventbridge-aws-lambda/) with AWS web-console screen-shots.

3. [Schedule a Serverless Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/scheduling-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-cloudwatch-events/) with AWS Step Functions and Amazon CloudWatch. You can also add delay as mentioned in this sample [Task Timer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html) project.